# Install Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I want to install Raspbian OS on my new Raspberry Pi and I heard that they
are ready made OS available all I need is to do unzip those files on my SD Card and everything will automatically installed and I will be ready to use it.

If any one know about it, then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: `all I need is to do unzip those files on my SD card` - not exactly how it works

Comment: Have a look at the official documentation on raspberrypi.org first:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download 'Raspbian with Desktop' https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ (no need to unzip)
2. Install Etcher https://etcher.io
3. Use Etcher to flash the 'Raspbian with Desktop' image to the sd card (min 8GB)
4. Place the sd card in your Pi and turn on

Comment: After that I don't need to start any process am I right ?

Comment: No, just turn on the Pi

Comment: I will give it a shot..

Comment: It worked but I am not able to SSH it..

Comment: I assume you've enabled ssh under Preferences,Raspberry Pi Configuration,Interfaces.

Comment: I don't have HDMI cable so I can't use GUI display

Comment: So what I have did is edited rc.local file and put this line before exit 0

"/etc/init.d/ssh start"

and it's still not working at all

note : I have created ssh file without extension on root directory as well

Comment: Suggest you post a new question about headless ssh setup. Assuming you’ve connected the Pi to your network https://howtoraspberrypi.com/how-to-raspberry-pi-headless-setup/

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple . Open chrome on another device and [install Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/).Enter your SD card into the other device and select your desired OS , Select your SD card as storage and write .
After writing , Remove the SD card from the other device and put it in your Raspberry Pi . You will see a screen saying

> Building SSH key ...

When the Raspberry Pi reboots , tadaaa! you have your OS .

Comment: This adds nothing to the accepted answer and misses out some essential steps.